# Geometry locus question

Tags: geometry

Find the coordinate(s) of the point(s) that satisfy the following conditions:

- equidistant from the points $(4,-7)$ and $(8,5)$
- distance of 5 from the point $(-5,1)$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Find",etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
The distance from a point $p_1=(x_1,y_1)$ to another point $p_2(x_2,y_2)$ is given by 
$$d\left(p_1,p_2\right) = \sqrt{\left(x_1-x_2\right)^2+\left(y_1-y_2\right)^2}$$

Now you are searching a special point $p=(x,y)$ that fullfills

1. $d\left(p,(4,-7)\right) = d\left(p,(8,5)\right)$
2. $d\left(p,(-5,1)\right) = 5$

Now set up the resulting equations and solve the non-linear system for $x$ and $y$

1. $(x-4)^2 + (y+7)^2 = (x-8)^2+(y-5)^2$
2. $(x+5)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 5^2$

Note that $x^2$ and $y^2$ cancels out in the first equation, so it is easy to solve this either to $x$ or $y$ and put it in the second equation.

Can you go ahead?